# Display sheet name in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

Is there any way to display a sheet name as the result of a function in a Google Spreadsheets (exactly like [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/219481/is-it-possible-to-get-the-sheetname), except in Google Sheets)?

Comment: Please see my answer to this question on stackoverflow : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53409439/279326

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Someone has written a script to do this. It is available in **Tools** > **Script gallery...**. Search for "sheet name" and install the script, then use it with `=getCurrentSheetName()`.

Comment: How to access this script in the "new" Google Sheets (which now uses an add-on store)?

Comment: This no longer works. Use the answer from @user93341. I went through the entire process to publish his function to the the Add-On Store and in the last step they wanted $5 to verify my account and I would be limited to publishing 20 items. Le sigh.

Answer (score 55):

Go to *Tools* → **Script Editor** and add this code:

```
function sheetName() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
}
```

In a cell where you want the sheet name add:

```
=sheetName()
```

*There was an issue with accessing sheet names via API functions shown below—where it only returned the first sheet name. [This was fixed in March 2015](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3522).*

Comment: Could you expand upon your answer for those of us that are not familiar with the script tool?

Comment: @Barry 1) Select Tools->Script Editor 2) In the resulting text file, add this function at the end 3) Click save 4) Now you can use this function in your sheet.

Comment: While this function works fine, it doesn't update when sheet name changes, so it's not actually useful.

Comment: @jesjimher according to [this Google Docs Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/AP6jO8C2lsA/u8ENUa4NTn8J), if one goes to the script editor and re-saves the script, going back to the sheet one sees that the tab names were properly updated.

Comment: I know, but it's confusing and totally opposite to how sheet formulas work. I expect a formula to update whenever its referenced data changes. Now this formula doesn't do that unless I open and save the source script. I could just enter sheet name by hand every time, saving the hassle.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a [Custom Function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#creating_a_custom_function) code snippet to get a spreadsheet name by it's [Identifier](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById%28String%29).

```
function GetSpreadsheetNameById(id) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  return ss.getName();
}
```

In a cell, pass a sheet Identifier (look in the spreadsheet URL for the identfier).

```
=GetSpreadsheetNameById('49nvkwOE-203nXDLGGJtg0htFKK020dsd939AAPZU')
```

Comment: This is just a slight change to @user93341 answer above.

Comment: This gives the following error: "You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. "

Comment: This returns the document's name instead of the sheet's name, replace `return ss.getName();` by `return ss.getActiveSheet().getName();` if you want the sheet's name (I actually needed the document's name, so thanks)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function getNameOfThisSheet() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
}
```

Paste it in **Tools > Script editor** and call the function from a cell like this:

```
=getNameOfThisSheet(NOW())
```

The `NOW()`, former `GoogleClock()`, parameter helps avoid issues with memoization.

Comment: GOOGLECLOCK() was replaced by NOW() by the other hand non-deterministic functions can't be used as arguments of custom functions.