# Dynamically Building Array Of Sheet Names From A Range Of Cells

Tags: google-sheets

I have a (fully working) formula which looks across all the other sheets referred to in an array, and sums up all the costs in one of the columns in those sheets.

It works just fine - my question is further down, but let me give context.

The formula is:

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX(
  QUERY(
    {
      '2017-01'!A$1:C$1000;
      '2017-02'!A$1:C$1000;
      '2017-03'!A$1:C$1000
    },
    CONCATENATE("select Col1, SUM(Col3) where Col1='", B2, "' group by Col1 label Col1 '', SUM(Col3) ''")
  ),
  0,  2
))
```

You can see the names of the sheets are simply `year-month` and the range is just the first three columns.

That formula is in entered into each of the "Total Cost" cells in a master sheet like this:

```
SKU     Code    Name    Total Cost
----------------------------------
0001    O8RE4   Things  3.93
0022    UO0V8   Stuff   28.39
```

And then each sheet called `2017-##` has data like this:

```
Code    Name    Cost
--------------------
O8RE4   Things  9.68
UO0V8   Stuff   11.86
```

The formula spits out just a single number (no headers) which is the total of all the costs for each of the "Things" and "Stuff" items in all the other sheets.

Great! :)

But each month I (or someone less technical!) need to add another reference to the list of sheets, and then copy that down the column.

***Question***: Is there a way to reference a range of cells in another sheet (*without* using Google Script), which contains a list like this, which we simply add a new row to each month?

```
'2017-01'!A$1:C$1000
'2017-02'!A$1:C$1000
'2017-03'!A$1:C$1000
'2017-04'!A$1:C$1000
'2017-05'!A$1:C$1000
```

Answer (score 1):

Without any custom function (Google Apps Script) the only thing you could do is have a sheet where you list them all out and reference them in that list.  Basically manually make the list and have your formula reference the cells listing the sheet names.

If you want to go the route of a custom function (I see you are saying without, but I have to be complete...)  see the thread [Display Sheet Name in Google Spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16009/display-sheet-name-in-google-spreadsheet).  You will need to use the [answers which tell you to create a custom function](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/60825/81031).  It will require a modification to loop through to each sheet, though.

Explanation of doing the option in the first paragraph:

The [INDIRECT() function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?rd=1) Returns a cell reference specified by a string.  So we can use that to combine a fixed range and the name of the sheet from a cell.  Placing the Sheet names in row A, and this formula in B1, you will get the contents of the sheet named in cell A2, rows A and B from the first row to the last:

```
=INDIRECT(A2 & "!A1:B")
```

Making an array of the calls and applying this to a query(), this will return all items in the sheets listed in cells A1 and A2:

```
=query({ INDIRECT(A1 & "!A1:B"); INDIRECT(A2 & "!A1:B")}, "select * where Col2 <> ''")
```

The challenge is getting all the items in row A to create the array you are referencing.  If you have the ability to write javascript, I would create a custom function.  Since you said you could do a new file each year, you can add additional `; INDIRECT(A2 & "!A1:B")` before the closing brace `}` and increment the A2 to A3, A4, etc...

I tried arrayformulas to get multiple INDIRECT() calls and a few other things but was not finding a good solution.

Comment: Thanks Karl but the answer you allude to in your first paragraph is what I am trying to do but failing. Can you please show an actual example of the syntax needed to refer to those other cells within the formula I gave? I am pretty good with Sheets but the syntax here is not clear. I'm not even sure it's possible at this stage.

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of sheets you may have?  Going open ended is not working out with anything I am trying.

Comment: Well I guess it could be done yearly so there could be 12. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Just looking at your answer again, you mention using a custom function to get sheet names. I know you are just being complete there but since you mention getting the sheet names I want to be sure that you know for this question I am asking about adding each new sheet name manually to a dedicated sheet which only has the sheet names listed. Then referring to that list from the above function. I could build this in script easily (I'm a programmer) but I want to know if there is syntax available to do it they way I am asking :)

Comment: @RedYeti See my edit.

Comment: Thanks - but I came up with that same solution too :(  The question is about the fact that I can't find a way to build an array from the list of references. The solution as you give it still requires the query to be edited with each additional sheet that is added. I know Javascript could do this. In fact it could do so much more (add the new sheet, with the correct name and headings, all ready for the new month's data) but as I mentioned, I am trying to work out if it's possible to do this with some standard syntax which I've yet to discover.

Comment: I believe you would not need to edit the equation, but place all 12 INDIRECT calls in and limit it to 12 months.  The challenge is the need for the indirect() function and it not working with ARRAYFORMULA().  That was the purpose of the question about a limited number of sheets.  I would personally create a custom function for this and I do not suggest that often.

Comment: Sorry but I am not seeing how the INDIRECT is helping here. If I have an INDIRECT call it must reference an actual, existing sheet. So I'd need to put all 12 sheets in place first. But if I need to do that, I can simply reference them in the same way as my original function (direct references, no INDIRECT). So I'm back to where I started surely? Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: Indirect allows you to name the sheet whatever you want and not have the name in the formula. If you create all the sheets up front and never change the names you don't need it.  If you have a possibly have a short list, you may also need to wrap each INDIRECT()  in an IF() such as `IF(ISBLANK(A4),,INDIRECT(A4 & "!A1:B"))` in which case hard coding the sheet name is not possible.  I am not saying it is the best answer in this case, I don't say it often, but I believe this is a case for a custom function. Above is just a (limited functionality) way to do it with the built in finctions.

Comment: Okay well the sheet names are all standard YYYY-MM so that's not really needed. I can see how it lets us list the sheet names. But yes - it seems that the answer to my question essentially is, that there is no syntax which allows this without using script. Thanks very much for confirming that!