# How can I get other sheet data with cell function when if I don't know sheet name

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I want to view other spreadsheets data with cell function in Google spreadsheet

`IMPORTRANGE` cell function is awesome
but, it required to know sheet name

> so question is how can I get other sheet data with cell function without sheet name

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Data sheet has four sheet,

1st sheet name is SN1

2nd sheet name is SN2

3rd sheet name is SN3

4th sheet name is SN4

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Location in script editor

1st sheet location number is 0

2nd sheet location number is 1

3rd sheet location number is 2

4th sheet location number is 3

In Google script, I used to location number when I need to change many different specific cell data from specific sheet even I don't know sheet names

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

It is quite easy to get data when I know the sheet name
`IMPORTRANGE("URL", "sheetname!A1:D21")`

but, how can I get other sheet data with cell function when if I don't know sheet name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display sheet name in Google Spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16009/display-sheet-name-in-google-spreadsheets)

Comment: Refer  StackOverflow [Is there a Google Sheets formula to put the name of the sheet into a cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45502538/1330560), and webapps [Display sheet name in Google Spreadsheets](Display sheet name in Google Spreadsheets)